# "yarn add" command add all libraries in package.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, react-native, yarnpkg

I have some issues when running "yarn add" command.
When I add 1 library, it will reinstall all libraries, dependencies in package.json too, it wastes a ton time to add 1 library.
In addition, I have another problem, I need to define $PATH for each terminal screen.
Is there any solution or I need reinstall my machine.
I'm using Macbook pro 2017.

Comment: Once you are installing one package only then you can use yarn add <package name> . If you want to install all modules then do yarn add

Comment: yeah, I mean that. ex: i run "yarn add react-native-xxxx", but it reinstall all modules instead of 1